How to connect ENT to boxes and why is the nut missing?

I know to push out the knockouts but how are these adapters supposed to fit into these boxes properly when the locknut is missing?

If your application is into a non-threaded hole then you need to obtain locknuts separately.
They don't include locknuts with PVC Terminal (male) Adapters either.

I see, so it’s at least the right adapters? Can I use a rigid locknut? https://www.homedepot.com/p/100111071

Let me add as well, I want to make sure that’s ok since the locknut is metal. I didn’t find any in plastic

Metal locknuts are the standard, in fact 30  years in the trade I don't remember seeing plastic.

Thank you, then I’ll get these rigid nuts above and call it the day. Marked as answer
